# Unable to Search Event Log with Runspaces in Powershell

Tags: powershell, runspace

I am searching a list of computers event logs for a specific event. This list is 7,000+ systems. I would love to have this utilize runspaces. I have the following code, yet it does not work. It looks like the return is null and of course causes the CSV export to fail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
# Max Runspaces
$Throttle = 5 #threads

# What is the total number of events to pull?
$eventMax = 10

# Which event log do we want to pull from?
$eventLog = "System"

$eventEntryID = "7023"

$eventMessage = "The Windows Modules Installer service terminated with the following error: 
The configuration registry database is corrupt."

# What is our source file, the one with ll the file names.
$computers = Get-Content "c:\temp\Louis\hostsins.txt"

# What is our CSV file
$outFile = "c:\temp\Louis\SearchEventLogResultsINS.csv"

$ScriptBlock = {
    Param (
        [string]$sComputer
    )

    $RunResult = Get-WinEvent -Oldest  -ComputerName $sComputer -FilterHashtable @{LogName = $eventLog; ID = $eventEntryID;} | 
                 where{$_.Message -eq $eventMessage} | 
                 Select machinename, TimeCreated, ID, LevelDisplayname, Message 
    write-host $RunResult

    Return $RunResult
}

$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Throttle)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = @()

$computers | % {

   write-host $_

   $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($_)
   $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
   $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        RunNum = $_
        Pipe = $Job
        Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
   }
}

Write-Host "Running.." -NoNewline
Do {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"

$Results = @()
ForEach ($Job in $Jobs){
    $Results += $Job.Pipe.EndInvoke($Job.Result)
}

$Results | Export-Csv $outFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are declaring variables outside of the runspace and attempting to use them in the runspace.

I see you pass in each computer with .addargument($_).  Nothing else though.  Runspaces are great for speed, but a little less convenient due to issues like this.

For more reading, check out [Dave Wyatt's post](http://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/more-on-powershell-multithreading-via-runspace-pools/), which includes other references.  Be sure to flip through the MSDN documentation on initialsessionstate, runspacefactory, runspacepool, and powershell, and explore and experiment with various properties and methods at the prompt.

I tried to rework your code, haven't tested it, but this should illustrate a workaround for you:

```
# Max Runspaces
$Throttle = 5 #threads

#Throw the stuff you want to pass in into a hashtable or whatever vehicle meets your needs
$params = @{
    eventMax = 10
    eventLog = "System"
    eventEntryID = "7023"
    eventmessage = "The Windows Modules Installer service terminated with the following error: 
The configuration registry database is corrupt."
    computer = $_
}

# What is our source file, the one with ll the file names.
$computers = Get-Content "c:\temp\Louis\hostsins.txt"

# What is our CSV file
$outFile = "c:\temp\Louis\SearchEventLogResultsINS.csv"

$ScriptBlock = {
    Param (
        [System.Collections.Hashtable]$hash
    )


    $RunResult = Get-WinEvent -Oldest  -ComputerName $hash.computer -FilterHashtable @{LogName = $hash.eventLog; ID = $hash.eventEntryID;} | 
                 where{$_.Message -eq $hash.eventMessage} | 
                 Select machinename, TimeCreated, ID, LevelDisplayname, Message 
    write-host $RunResult

    Return $RunResult
}

$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Throttle)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = @()

$computers | % {

    $params = @{
        eventLog = "System"
        eventEntryID = "7023"
        eventmessage = "The Windows Modules Installer service terminated with the following error: 
    The configuration registry database is corrupt."
        computer = $_
    }

   write-host $_


   $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($params)
   $Job.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
   $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        RunNum = $_
        Pipe = $Job
        Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()
   }
}

Write-Host "Running.." -NoNewline
Do {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"

$Results = @()
ForEach ($Job in $Jobs){
    $Results += $Job.Pipe.EndInvoke($Job.Result)
}

$Results | Export-Csv $outFile
```

Cheers!